# Entity Framework Context Not Acting As I Expected

Tags: entity-framework, transactions, dbcontext

I am seeing something in Entity Framework that has me thinking that I either completely misunderstand how the database context works, or EF is actually broken (and I know that most likely means I just don't get it).

Consider the following scenario:

In the database I have a bunch of Student Attendance records, and they all have a code marked as P for present.

Then we have something akin to the following:

```
public void SetAttendance(int dayId,int attendanceId, int attendanceId, String mark)
{ 
    updateAttendance = new StudentAttendance()
    {
     Code=String.Empty,
     AttendanceId=attendanceId,
     DayId = dayId
    };
    context.Attach(updateAttendance);
//I don't save changes yet because I now need to do some logic
var markedAttendanceCount = context.StudentAttendance.Where(att=> !String.IsNullOrEmpty(att.Code) && att.DayId == dayId).Count();

var allAttendanceCount = context.StudentAttendance.Where(att=> att.DayId == dayId).Count();

    var updateDay = new ClassDay() 
    {
       DayId = dayId,
       AllMarked = markedAttendanceCount = allAttendanceCount
     };
  context.Attach(updateDay);
  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I would expect that if I were to call that SetAttendance method as follows:

```
myworker.SetAttendance(10,20,String.Empty);
```

That it should properly recognize that the attendance for the day is not fully marked.  What I am instead seeing is that my look int query against context.StudentAttendance is asking the database.  As such, my detection of the day's status change is always one behind.

I thought that the context was basically supposed to be smart enough to let you write something like this.  In essence, I had always had the impression that the db context lets you essentially work with a serializable transaction kind of behavior.  As you make changes to the data through your context, those changes will reflect in queries against the context.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

EF doesn't work that way, no. For performance reasons basically.

However, `context.StudentAttendance.Local` exposes a set containing the added entities. It also contains any entity previously loaded by the context in a query. If you like you can load the whole DbSet into memory as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/jj592872.aspx however this is not advisable for large datasets.

Also, you should be using `context.Add()` rather than `context.Attach()`. The latter is for entities which already exist in the database.

Comment: Thanks.  In the real code, I do differentiate and do context.Add if it is a new mark and attach if I am updating.  I tried to water down the example to make what I was asking more clear.  

I can see what you are talking about, and appreciate the response.  I am going to have to evaluate how I can go about my particular need in light of my better understanding now :)

Answer (score 0):

It's true that you don't fully understand how EF works, but I think EF is to blame for that. You're asking a very good and valid question.

NHibernate, as opposed to EF, has this [*AutoFlush* feature](http://rasmuskl.dk/2011/06/15/nhibernate-flushing-and-you/). This means that "at any moment" it may commit changes to the database in order to keep local changes and database content in sync without the developer's intervention. In your case, it would have saved the new `StudentAttendance` before querying existing ones from the database. So if the new one matched the predicate (`DayId == dayId`) it would have contributed to `allAttendanceCount`. This feature, when understood well, allows for a very intuitive way of dealing with data, exactly the way you expected EF to behave.

The truth is, however, that AutoFlush has always eluded developers, so they often just disabled it. As a developer you want to have full control, you don't want to depend on some smart feature that seems to have a life of its own. (Even though the reality is that you probably just didn't take the time to fully get it).

I can imagine that for this reason, the EF team decided not to implement such a feature.

So what to do in your case? Not easy. When after adding the new `StudentAttendance` you'd do...

```
context.StudentAttendance.Load();
```

(assuming that you have a `DbContext`, though your "`context.Attach`" doesn't seem to be in line that).

And then...

```
var allAttendanceCount = context.StudentAttendance
                                .Local // <= Local! Includes the new item
                                .Where(att=> att.DayId == dayId)
                                .Count();
```

...you'd have the desired result. But of course, loading all `StudentAttendance` records locally is a tremendous overkill.

One simple alternative is to to the count as you do now and add 1 to it.

Another alternative is to mimic autoflush, sort of, and save the new `StudentAttendance` before doing the count. But then you'd have to wrap everything in a `TransactionScope`. One advantage is that you'd have the very latest value of `allAttendanceCount`.